# WSO2 APIM Analytics 3.1.0 server's Dashboard profile errors out while starting and the Analytics Dashboard doesn't open

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I was following one of the tutorials from WSO2's learning website and tried to setup the Analytics server 3.1.0 with APIM 3.1.0. I followed the below sequence of starting the servers.

1. APIM Analytics worker profile
2. APIM server
3. APIM Analytics dashboard profile

The APIM Analytics worker profile and the APIM server started without any issue.

But on starting the Analytics dashboard profile, I am getting the below error though i can see message at the last that APIM Analytics Server started.

```
 **ERROR** {msf4j-core} - [SCR] Error while trying to bind reference Reference[name = microservice, interface = org.wso2.msf4j.Microservice, policy = dynamic, cardinality = 0..n, target = null, bind = addService, unbind = removeService]
        Details:
        Problematic reference = Reference[name = microservice, interface = org.wso2.msf4j.Microservice, policy = dynamic, cardinality = 0..n, target = null, bind = addService, unbind = removeService]
        of service component = org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MicroServicesServerSC
        component implementation class = org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MicroservicesServerSC
        located in bundle with symbolic name = msf4j-core
        bundle location = reference:file:../lib/plugins/msf4j-core_2.7.7.jar java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ComponentReference.bind(ComponentReference.java:376)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bindReference(ServiceComponentProp.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.dynamicBind(InstanceProcess.java:416)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:334)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:915)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:862)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:801)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:225)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:464)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:482)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:999)
        at org.wso2.carbon.uiserver.internal.deployment.msf4j.MicroservicesRegistrar.register(MicroservicesRegistrar.java:154)
        at org.wso2.carbon.uiserver.internal.deployment.msf4j.MicroservicesRegistrar.lambda$register$3(MicroservicesRegistrar.java:144)
        at org.wso2.carbon.uiserver.internal.deployment.msf4j.MicroservicesRegistrar$$Lambda$282.00000000160C0730.apply(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
        at java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1556)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:496)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:241)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
        at org.wso2.carbon.uiserver.internal.deployment.msf4j.MicroservicesRegistrar.register(MicroservicesRegistrar.java:145)
        at org.wso2.carbon.uiserver.internal.deployment.listener.AppTransportBinder.appDeploymentEvent(AppTransportBinder.java:76)
        at org.wso2.carbon.uiserver.internal.io.deployment.ArtifactAppDeployer.publishAppDeploymentEvent(ArtifactAppDeployer.java:154)
        at org.wso2.carbon.uiserver.internal.io.deployment.ArtifactAppDeployer.deploy(ArtifactAppDeployer.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngine.lambda$deployArtifacts$0(DeploymentEngine.java:291)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngine$$Lambda$237.0000000015F30F90.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngine.deployArtifacts(DeploymentEngine.java:282)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.RepositoryScanner.sweep(RepositoryScanner.java:112)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.RepositoryScanner.scan(RepositoryScanner.java:68)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngine.start(DeploymentEngine.java:121)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngineListenerComponent.onAllRequiredCapabilitiesAvailable(DeploymentEngineListenerComponent.java:216)
        at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupComponentManager.lambda$notifySatisfiableComponents$7(StartupComponentManager.java:266)
        at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupComponentManager$$Lambda$159.0000000013DAFD90.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
        at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupComponentManager.notifySatisfiableComponents(StartupComponentManager.java:252)
        at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupOrderResolver$1.run(StartupOrderResolver.java:204)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.wso2.msf4j.util.RuntimeAnnotations (initialization failure)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializationAlreadyFailed(J9VMInternals.java:96)
        at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MicroservicesServerSC.addMicroserviceToRegistry(MicroservicesServerSC.java:421)
        at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MicroservicesServerSC.addService(MicroservicesServerSC.java:108)
        ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.Class$Atomic
        at org.wso2.msf4j.util.RuntimeAnnotations.<clinit>(RuntimeAnnotations.java:110)
        at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MicroservicesServerSC.addMicroserviceToRegistry(MicroservicesServerSC.java:421)
        at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MicroservicesServerSC.addService(MicroservicesServerSC.java:108)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.Class$Atomic
        at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:332)
        at org.wso2.msf4j.util.RuntimeAnnotations.<clinit>(RuntimeAnnotations.java:58)
        ... 52 more

[2020-07-22 21:36:30,653]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.uiserver.internal.deployment.listener.AppTransportBinder} - Web app 'policies' is available at 'https://10.184.69.117:9643/policies'.
[2020-07-22 21:36:30,662]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.CarbonStartupHandler} - **WSO2 API Manager Analytics Server started in 10.285 sec**
```

And, when I try to open the link : https://localhost:9643/analytics-dashboard/ , it gives an error which says: "Problem accessing: /analytics-dashboard/. Reason: Not Found".

Need help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Java are you using?

According to the error, you are looking for a class that does not exist, it may be a standard class that only has one version, I recommend using Java 11 for this version.

Comment: Hi Flaviano, I am using jdk-8.0.202.08. If i use jdk 11, the WSO2 APIM server doesn't start and fails with an error: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=.\lib\endorsed;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\jre\lib\endorsed;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\lib\endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.